# Elixir check if given day is holiday

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Is it possible to check if a given date is a holiday in US using the Elixir language?

In Ruby we have a gem called [holiday](https://github.com/holidays/holidays). Am wondering how to make something in Elixir.

Comment: You could consider reading in the associated yaml file for US holidays from that Gem: `https://github.com/holidays/holidays/blob/master/definitions/us.yaml`. Sorry nothing better to offer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can search for mix dependencies(similar to gems) on https://hex.pm/. Currently there are none available for US. The closest you can get is this https://hex.pm/packages/japanese_holiday